# better way of contouring velocity magnitude with time as x axis

Tags: matlab

I am not getting a nice pcolor plot, so i need to do a contour plot of velocity magnitude with depth (contour lines) and time as x axis. I know that there are other options but i prefer contour plot.

```
figure;

timeC = x(in);                %  811 X 1 matrix
depC = [1.20,2.20,3.20];
depC = depC';                 % 3 X 1 matrix


ur = dat3(in,1:3);            % 811 X 3 matrix
vr = dat4(in,1:3);            % 811 X 3 matrix
[THETAc,Rc] = cart2pol(vr,ur);
vMag = Rc';                   % 3 X 811 matrix

hpc = pcolor(timeC,depC,vMag);
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');
set(hpc,'EdgeColor','none');
caxis([0,0.2]);
t = colorbar('peer',gca);
set(gca, 'xlim', [min(timeC) max(timeC)]);
datetick(handles.axes4,'x', 15, 'keeplimits'); % does not work with pcolor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `help contour` or `help contourf`. You will find that the function arguments are very similar to pcolor, so you can probably just replace `pcolor` with `contour`, i.e.

```
hcnt = contour(timeC,depC,vMag);
```

See the documentation for further customization options.